# SonarQube HTTP header authentication

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, sonarqube

Has anyone successfully implemented Sonarqube based on documentation given [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication) ?

I have a project dashboard, which authenticates using my company's LDAP. The requirement is to use this authentication and invoke Sonar using X-Forwarded-Login & X-Forwarded-Name headers as mentioned in the documentation. Is there a way to achieve this ? Based on my analysis, this is not possible, since we cannot set headers for external redirects.

Is there anyway to achieve the stated objective ?

Comment: You need to use a reverse proxy or something like that.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing -  Reversed proxied the request and set the header. Worked perfectly.